# Create Index thru SPARK for JDBC

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create Index on Postgres Table thru Spark and the code is as below:

```
   val df3 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://URL")                                                          
   .option("user", "user")
  .option("password", "password")
  .option("dbtable", "(ALTER TABLE abc.test1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (test))as t")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .option("lowerBound", 1L)
  .option("upperBound", 10000000L)
  .option("numPartitions", 100)
  .option("fetchSize", "1000000")
  .load()
```

The error is

Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE"

Just wondering can we do that or the above Data frame is wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: why don't you use regular jdbc for that task ? you are not reading or writing anything

Comment: Check my answer here about dropping table : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599873/dropping-mysql-table-with-sparksql/35600318#35600318 The logic shouldn't be much different

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am looking in spark-scala.

Comment: Thanks i am able to achieve that. Bur after that i am calculating time dfifference as below: